# Openstack Kolla VM not ssh or ping

Tags: ssh, ping, kolla-ansible

I successfully installed OpenStack kolla Victoria release. After that i executed init-runonce and VM(cirros) is spinned up and running. I assigned floating IPs as per [run-init](https://github.com/openstack/kolla-ansible/blob/stable/victoria/tools/init-runonce). Everything is configured as expected i.e. no error at all.

The problem is that i am not able to ping/ssh floating Ip of VM.I checked in the security group rules (ICMP & SSH)are added as well  by script init-runonce. In my configuration eno2 was without IP, which is in br-ex. However, br-ex doesn't have any ip.

Can you please guide me how can i fix this issue?